# React native Pod install getting Permission denied

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, permission-denied, mkdir

I'm created new project using command **react-native init testprog**
then change dir to testprog and pod install but it give permission denied error

```
$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Downloading dependencies
Installing CocoaAsyncSocket (7.6.5)
Installing DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
Installing FBLazyVector (0.64.0)
Installing FBReactNativeSpec (0.64.0)
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
mkdir -p /Volumes/MACMINI DATA SSD/testprog/node_modules/react-native/scripts/../React/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec && touch /Volumes/MACMINI DATA SSD/testprog/node_modules/react-native/scripts/../React/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec.h /Volumes/MACMINI DATA SSD/testprog/node_modules/react-native/scripts/../React/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm

mkdir: /Volumes/MACMINI: Permission denied
```

I was try following things but it not working

- update pod
- reinstall pod
- **chown** command for ~/.cocoapods
- **chown** command for ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
- **chown** command for /usr/local/bin/npm
- **chown** command for /usr/local/bin/npx
- **chown** command for /usr/local/bin/node

> What is wrong?
> How to resolve it?

Pod version: 1.10.1
Os Version: 10.15.7
react-native Version: 0.64.0

Answer (score 16):

There can be multiple reason for this.

- There is one solution which always worked for me is

> sudo pod install --allow-root

- Go to your ios folder -> Go to get info -> read & write (to your user) -> click on small setting button below there -> Apply to enclosed items.

Comment: I'm installing pod in external HDD and HDD name is "MACMINI DATA" so rename HDD name to "MACMINI_DATA" then restart pc and now it working. Issue was space in HDD name.

Comment: 1st option worked for me!

Comment: This worked for me
Go to your ios folder -> Go to get info -> read & write (to your user) -> click on small setting button below there -> Apply to enclosed items.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

try `sudo chmod -R 777 node_modules` then install pod again

Comment: How does this apply to installing Cocoapods?